# Java: How to increase the warrior's level?

Tags: java, game-center

So the output for the warrior's level is not increasing as their experience go up. Warrior 1 starting level is 20 and warrior 2 is 18. I'm trying to increase each warrior's level by printing it out on Game.java file. I tried to increment the expLevel and then experience but it shows an error. What is the best way to increase each of the warrior's level?

```
public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Part 3 of ICE16 then ICE17 edition
    
    // List of weapons
    Weapon mean = new Weapon("Mean Words", 1, "Mean words cause very little damage", 4); 
    Weapon bat = new Weapon("Baseball Bat", 10, "Some properties get destroyed", 4); 
    Weapon gun = new Weapon("Handgun", 100, "Stronger than a baseball bat", 4); 
    Weapon bazooka = new Weapon("Bazooka", 200, "Major destruction", 4); 
    Weapon laChancla = new Weapon("La Chancla", 4000, "Total annihilation", 4); 
    
    // Warriors 
    Warrior w1 = new Warrior(28, "Skeletor", 20, mean); 
    Warrior w2 = new Warrior(19, "Striker", 18, bat); 
    
    // Changes 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        w1.attack(); 
        w2.attack(); 
    } 
    
    w1.attack(); 
    
    w1.assignWeapon(bazooka); 
    
    w2.attack();
    
    w2.assignWeapon(laChancla); 
    
    w1.attack(); 
    
    System.out.println(w1.getExpLevel()); 
    System.out.println(w2.getExpLevel());

}
```

}

Here is a warrior class:

```
public class Warrior {
// Part 2 of ICE16 then ICE17 edition 

// 4 properties: int age, String name, int expLevel, Weapon weapon 
private int age; 
private String name; 
private int expLevel; 
private Weapon weapon; 
private int experience = 0; 

// Create a constructor that assigns each value to the property 
public Warrior(int age, String name, int expLevel, Weapon weapon) {
    this.age = age; 
    this.name = name; 
    this.expLevel = expLevel; 
    this.weapon = weapon; 
}

// Method 1 
public void attack() {
    System.out.println("Warrior, " + name + " with experience level " + expLevel + " attacks!");
    // Call the strike method from the weapon class
    this.weapon.strike(); 
    
    if (weapon.strike()) {
        experience++; 
    } 
    if (experience >= 4) {
        expLevel++; 
    } else {
        System.out.println("The warrior cannot attack");
    }
} 

// Method 2 
public void assignWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
    this.weapon = weapon; 
    System.out.println(this.name + " now has " + weapon.getType());
} 

public int getExpLevel() {
    return expLevel; 
}
```

}

Here is a weapon class:

```
public class Weapon {
// Part 1 of ICE16 then ICE17 edition

// 3 properties: String type, int power, and String strikeMessage 
private String type; 
private int power; 
private String strikeMessage; 
private int health = 4; 

// In class Weapon, create a constructor that assigns values to each of these internal private properties of the class in the order above. 
public Weapon (String type, int power, String strikeMessage, int health) {
    this.type = type; 
    this.power = power; 
    this.strikeMessage = strikeMessage; 
    this.health = health; 
}

// Method 1
public int getPower() {
    return power; 
}

// Method 2 
public boolean strike() {
    System.out.println("Weapon of type " + type + " has power " + power);
    System.out.println(strikeMessage);
    
    if (health < 0) {
        System.out.println("Weapon " + this.type + " cannot strike because it's damaged");
        return true;
    } else {
        health--; 
        return false; 
    }
    
}

// Method 3
public void setPower(int power) {
    this.power = power; 
} 

// Weapon's Health Level 

public String getType() {
    return type; 
}
```

}

Comment: _"I tried to increment the expLevel and then experience but it shows an error"_ - What's the error? You should post that as part of your question.

Comment: It cannot be resolved as a variable.

Comment: I ran your program and don't get any errors. It ran, just the levels did not change at the end.

Comment: I suggest check the logic in the Warrior#attack() method and Weapon#strike()

Comment: Found it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code to increase `explevel` is within an `if` statement that will only increase the `explevel` if the `explevel` is already `4 or greater`.

This means that all `Warrior` instances with a level of 3 or lower can never increase their level (until you change this code).